# Should Combined Flair be offered?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flair

Currently **flair** is offered on a per site (MSO, SO, SF and in the future SU).

Should their be a *combined* "piece of flair", or even better a simple XML that returns a users flair from all sites so we can roll-our-own flair display widgets.

Comment: Related to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/529/how-about-links-from-one-users-profiles-to-his-her-other-so-site-profiles/545#545

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, I was just discussing this with someone else. I like the idea of being able to see multiple account details in one place *much* more than transferred or combined rep. The numbers represent slightly different things, after all.

It's possible that *badge totals* could be combined between the sites, however - the rep would give you a good general idea of how they're distributed anyway, and it would save having too much visual clutter.

Comment: This should be trivial with the API now.

Comment: I notice that on the Area 51 site, when you commit to a proposal, there is combined flair snippet.  Can this be disttributed, as this is exactly the graphic I want on my tumblr site....

If not, is the above answer by Jon Skeet possible yet?

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange network profiles:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/stack-exchange-network-profiles/

your network flair is available from the **flair tab on your user page** on each site. For example:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/159141/alex-gray?tab=flair