# How about links from one user's profiles to his/her other SO site profiles?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page

When surfing on one of the SO sites (SO, SF or Meta, and soon SU), and accessing a user's profile, it would be easier to have links to his/her profile on the other sites.

It would:

- give us a better view of his profile ("developer only?, IT guy? advanced computer user?")
- increase the visibility of the other SO sites ("wait a minute, there is a ServerFault site? or a Meta site? Interesting, I will check them out")
- allow the user to quickly switch between his/her different profiles and check the evolution of the rep or comments on the other site.

Those links could be located on:

- the profile page,
- but also on the "recent" page.
  (in the latter case, they would be visible only by the user, allowing for a quick check of latest responses/comments between the sites)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "accounts" tab on the user profile now fills this role.

Answer (score 1):

I like it.  I think the best way to do it would be with the badges too.

Answer (score 1):

It would be great to have flair pointing to the other sides. This would give me username, karma, badges. It should be put on the profile page, imho.

Here in Meta, it would even be interesting to have the username, karma and badges in the card about the author of a question or anser for the underlying SO site.

Comment: Wait, what about a "consolidate" flair badge, displaying points and badges of all 3 or 4 SO site? ;)

Comment: Great idea. Only draw back: I would then need the same username and login, wouldn't I?

Comment: Yes, that would encourage users to actively explore the "openId" way to log in.

Comment: That would only work for people not using openIds that present differently to different sites (like Google's, for example)

Answer (score 1):

If a person is participating on all Stack Exchange sites and creates an account, why can't he/she copy his/her profile details (except tags maybe) quickly? Please instate this as a feature.

I had to create a profile and fill in the form 4 times to have account on all SO sites.

Comment: you can, click the "copy profile" button on the accounts tab of your user page.