# Single location for SO/SF/SU user info

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, hyperlinks, linked-accounts

With the addition of Server Fault and the future addition of Super User, I can imagine it gets relatively hard to keep track of all that is going on without having three windows open at the same time and constantly refreshing each of your recent activity pages.

Would it be possible/feasible to create some sort of mini-site that would allow a user to keep track of their account statistics over all the sites and see the recent activity on them (new comments, answers, rep gains/losses, etc.) in one place?

All I am really looking for is almost a clone of the current Recent Activity page (the one you click on the envelope to get to) that would show the activity from all the sites (as long as you have them linked, such as with the same OpenID).

If you wanted to take it another step forward, you could take the personal profile page and modify it to allow for the inclusion of all sites at one time as well.

Comment: Isn't that an at leat partial duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/529/how-about-links-from-one-users-profiles-to-his-her-other-so-site-profiles ?

Comment: VonC: Yes, it is partially related in the sense of somehow linking your different site profiles together. While his is looking for just easy links to click between the set, I am proposing something a bit more centralized.

Comment: @TheTXI: All right. I like that approach too, although I think it may be more complex to implement that just add a few links.

Comment: VonC: Of course it would be more complex to implement than simple links, not disputing that at all. I have no problem with your suggestion (sorry for not realizing it was yours when I first read it). I wouldn't be offended or put off if your suggestion was implemented over mine, because it would still address the need. I just sort of prefer to see everything in one location rather than having to click around for it :)

Comment: Not exactly what you've asked for, but maybe it's interesting for you: http://code.google.com/p/open-so-frontend/

Comment: @J.S.: Especially when I don't get blocked further on for periodically polling my own public profile - and do some more developments to the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tabbed browsing helps a lot. If you read the questions you have to open it separately anyway. Maybe I should mention that I have 20 browser windows open and each contains at least 4 tabs.
No, not all for SO ;-)
But I'm browsing that way all the time.

Comment: I usually keep my different sites open on different tabs as well, but it just isn't very efficient to have to look at one, look at the other, etc. etc. 

Also, with your browsing habits I would have to wonder if you have any time/space/RAM left to do any other tasks.

Comment: RAM is overrated ;-)

Comment: John: Until you don't have any more :)

Comment: Polling the 4 trilogy windows on a regular basis sounds like a job for a computer .. what I would like to have is one page, that shows me the content for "interesting" tags on all 4 sites combined... exists or is this my project?

Comment: It's your project, lexu. Or you have a look at that tool, I mention in the comments to TheTXI's question. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Although it does not push notifications or show *all* recent activity, [StackCenter](http://stackcenter.quickmediasolutions.com) may be what you are looking for. It shows recent comments made to you on any StackExchange site you are registered on. It even has a global reputation graph.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

*If you like StackCenter, please vote for it [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/1114/stackcenter-your-one-stop-for-everything-stackexchange).*

Answer (score 2):

The [Stack Exchange network profile](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/stack-exchange-network-profiles/) lists all your associated accounts profile info, with rep & graph in one place

[image: Stack Exchange Network profile]