# Want to have a single page to view recent comments and replies for all web sites - SO, SF, SU

Tags: feature-request, comments, user-accounts, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Trilogy Portal: Community Colloboration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6033/trilogy-portal-community-colloboration)
>   [Single location for SO/SF/SU user info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/587/single-location-for-so-sf-su-user-info)

Just what my subject says...

If I have associated accounts on StackOverflow, ServerFault, SuperUser, I would like to see what happens with all my Q & A on all web sites on a single page without a need to click on 3 different sites.

If this is not possible from technical point of view to have a detailed summary for all assosiated accounts, at least I would like to see a popup informer that tells me about recent answers and comments not only on the current site, but on other sites too.

For example when I log in to SO, I may see something like this

> You have 1 reply. Click here.
>
> You also have 1 reply and 2 comments on
>   ServerFault. Click here.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6033

Comment: You don't have a problem with multiple accounts do you? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10668/

Comment: Exact dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/587/single-location-for-so-sf-su-user-info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is keeping up the streak of users asking for the same "centralized locale" for their accounts. I don't know what else can really be said about it. I've said before that it would be nice, but I still don't think it is that big of a deal that we don't get it (maybe I'm in a very small minority here based on the posts that keep coming in here about the subject).

Comment: +1 Agreed. Jeff has made it clear it is not high on the list, and people still don't seem to search first :(