# "Stack-overview" a dashboard for cross site users

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, superuser, serverfault

I have now signed up to the 4 sites and I am trying to swap between them easily. 
In my usual slackness and developer mindframe I was wonding if there were any plans to have an overview for a person to see all their stuff across all the sites in one screen.
A sort of mash up or web parts or something.

Comment: You mean this?: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/587/

Comment: Suggested several times, denied several times more for good measure.

Comment: I think we should start taking bets on when the next one of these suggestions is going to come up. I'm gonna go ahead and say Saturday 8/8/09, 21:23 UTC. Price is Right rules.

Comment: How about a jackofall.com that is just an aggregation of SO, SF, SU and Meta...?

Comment: @beggs: And how long until the jackoffall.com jokes start. Oh, wait, four minutes.

Comment: Turns out six. My browser said four when I posted that :)

Comment: @Eric, that's the fun part. Right?

Comment: Heh, yeah alright, I read through a bunch of them when it came up with the list but the ones I saw didn't seem to match what I was thinking.