# Can access to all SE sites that I am a member of be provided from the SE website?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, user-accounts

I have only recently started getting into the SE network of sites. As a new user it was a little confusing that I had to create a new account for each site, as I would have imagined that these would be combined into one account. I now understand why, Open ID requires new authorization for each site so it is out of SE's control.

The SE drop box on the top left corner is nice, but is it possible to get a feed of information about activity, my own and others, from all the SE sites **which I am a member of** in one area.

I know this will probably sound similar to this question, [Create one page on SE to show my notifications for all SE, etc sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60602/create-one-page-on-se-to-show-my-notifications-for-all-se-etc-sites), but instead of only getting a feed of network wide replies I think it would be good to get a feed of information from each site that I have an account, all consolidated into one overall feed on the SE website. This way I could view the *interesting, featured* and *hot* feeds of multiple sites at one time. For example I could see SO and Tex questions together.

"But you can already view multiple site feeds at once by choosing sites in the right hand side of the SE page!!" Yes, that is true. I couple of problems with this: I have to manually select the sites (not a big deal, but automatic select of the sites that you are a member seems like a smart option). It is also displayed in a different style to the feeds in the full sites, there is no way to switch between the *interesting* or *month* viewing modes etc.

The other area of improvement is the User page, which again could consolidate statistics, activity, favourites etc into one place. This is very similar to the suggestions in the previous question that was linked above, but it is something that I think would be a very useful feature, which would still benefit from more discussion.

Comment: Check out http://stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi Chris, sorry if I hadn't made it clear but I was trying to ask about improving the www.stackexchange.com interface to give it the  appearance of an individual SE site, except it would include information from all the sites that I have an account on. It would be great to be able to go to one page and see the questions from all sites with which I have an account, without having to manually set up tags or de-select sites.

Comment: Actually there appears to be a question that I missed on my initial search that pretty much covers what I am after: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74643/a-profile-page-for-all-the-stackexchange-accounts-from-account-owners-pov

Comment: @StevenVascellaro: Dupe doesn't seem to cover the site feed combining aspect *at all*.