# Display SO/SU/SF reputation on every platform

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation

Wouldn't it be nice to check someone's reputation on ServerFault or SuperUser even if you're currently browsing StackOverflow?

So you could check, how active he/she is on other platform and browse his/her profile on the over there.

That's why I propose to implement a little badge in the profile page which shows the reputation on the other platforms.

A nice addon could be to see the reputation if you hover over link to user's profile right in a question.

So: What is your opinion about my proposal?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116/should-combined-flair-be-offered

Answer (score 7, accepted):

New experimental feature

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/32043?tab=accounts

more work coming on this.

Comment: Will this be available on SO/SF as well, or just MetaSO?

Comment: Thumbs up to "experimental CNAME meta" ! :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you could add your [flair bladge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair) in the editable right box of your profile page, it would be just enough.

Right now, the iframe/script is rightfully stripped from the textarea.

Comment: This could be done with a custom tag, all the work being done safely in the SO/SF/MSO/SU engine.

Comment: That's exactly what I had in mind :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how useful this would be.

While I have registered and answered a couple of questions over on ServerFault I'm not a sys admin so my rep is stuck resolutely at 101.

I will register and contribute on SuperUser - if nothing else I'm bound to have PC problems I need fixing at some point - but I'm sure my involvement level will be different again.

Will having 3 potentially wildly differing numbers tell you anything useful?

Answer (score 0):

I think, they should be unified to one single reputation score which is the same on the different platforms.

Sure the topic's are really distinct. But does that really matter?

Comment: Yes, it does matter.

Comment: I'm guessing this is going to be one of those perennial requests that will pop up for as long as the site exists... this is a bad idea. I am a programmer and a super user who happens to be required to run a server - hence why my SO and SU rep is higher than my SF rep. You do not want my programming cred to unduly lend trust (and tools) to my server account. ;) See numerous other questions related to this for more detailed reasoning than I can fit in a comment.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/why-not-merge-reputation-across-so-sf-and-su (which happens to be on the "related" sidebar)