# Why not combine reputations from different StackOverflow sites?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why not merge reputation across SO, SF, and SU?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/why-not-merge-reputation-across-so-sf-and-su)

Why not combine the reputations from different stackoverflow sites? This would probably encourage people to post to the correct site - as it is, they are effectively penalized by distributing their questions to the correct location.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/why-not-merge-reputation-across-so-sf-and-su

Answer (score 3):

No. Bad idea.

Different sites, different users and skills, different trust in audience.

Just because a user is rampant on SU posting and repping hard with those types of questions/answers doesn't mean they should be seen in the same kind of light if they were posting on SF or SO.

Right now you can have a combined value if you go to the Accounts tab in your profile and use your calculator application of choice.

They're not penalised, they're just facing a different crowd.

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm no programmer or IT specialist, but I do consider myself a super user.

Therefore my rep from SU wouldn't represent any knowledge in the specific domain of SO/SF. It would go against the idea of rep I think, since rep should represent that you have a reputation on that certain topic. Not on the entire trilogy...

Answer (score 1):

Or perhaps have a combo rep value in addition to the rep on each site.  That way each subject site still has separate rep for the individual, but you could also see the combined rep for a user.