# reputation scores should be combined if accounts are integrated

Tags: discussion, reputation, linked-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why not merge reputation across SO, SF, and SU?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/why-not-merge-reputation-across-so-sf-and-su)

I am talking about surepuser, serverfault and stackoverflow altogether.

There are two reason for this opinion, one is philosophical and the other is practical.
Let me start with the philosophical first.

`mail.google.com`, `reader.google.com` and `www.google.com` provides three different functionalities, yet, same person, log in once, and he's logged in to all of them.

In practice, many developers are ending up installing their software on server machines, many of them are required to maintain these bytes regularly or even build some other tools that will do this for automatically (serverfault.com) - That's why I see no reason having two separate accounts for the same

senior developers usually can be considered as power users, so why would it be a different for the very same developer when posting a question or answering one on suerpuser.com.

and most of all, having meta.stackoverflow on a separate account is totally mistaken - imagine a guy scoring 27k on stackoverflow. One day, this fellow has an idea how to improve the site so to make it even easier to answer questions.

If this fellow answered 12k questions a year, his suggestion must be considered differently that one who answered 3 question a year, right? Since he's a proven heavy user of the site and a major contributor. Yet, when he will first login to the meta.so and create the account one will not notice their stackoverflow activity and might ignore their feature request altogether.

Comment: This question has been duplicated over and over and over again. The only valid point is Meta reputation.

Comment: dupe http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10967/why-not-combine-reputations-from-different-stackoverflow-sites-closed

Comment: dupe http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/why-not-merge-reputation-across-so-sf-and-su

Comment: relevant http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15117/should-so-rep-be-considered-in-su-and-sf

Comment: If credit score was correlated to SO reputation, Jon Skeet could apply and be successfully granted over 50 million UniverseDenoms (UD) from The Bank of The Universe. The exchange rate is roughly 10^256:1 USD to UD.

Comment: Where have you heard reputation being called credit score?

Comment: Can I now use my SO Rep to apply for a mortgage?

Comment: @random, I changed the title from credit score to reputation score. sorry for this mistake, English is not my default. besides, according to the jokes over here, seems like it caused some fun and joy to some people.

Comment: +1 for fun and joy! Not enough of that usually. Kudos friend.

Answer (score 3):

The three sites don't answer questions on the same topic.

Your reputation represents your contribution to the community on the topic at hand.

Doesn't follow. I know mounds more about programming than servers. Why on Earth should I have 14k on ServerFault, when I can't answer 99% of the questions there?

Your analogy is false too. On Google you don't earn points from the community on different topics.

Comment: ..what he said.

Comment: your answer make sense as for superuser and serverfault. but not regarding meta.stack and stack. 

Matter of fact, if you have 14K in stackoverflow, I think having that appeared at serverfault can simply help sys-admins (which are the most active community at that site) treat your questions with the respect you deserve ;-)
I personally feel odd having 4 accounts for the same operation. even though all 4 sites somewhat different.

Comment: But I don't deserve that respect. I haven't done as much as other users in the ServerFault community. That said, I'd like to think people look past rep for respect. A good answer is a good answers, regardless of it's poster. That said, meta is a special situation, but I still feel it's different enough to not warrant merging. One could be the best at the Trilogy topics, but be terribly uneducated in the Way of Meta.