# Should we give users their highest SO, SF or SU rep. on meta

Tags: feature-request, reputation, meta

I'm active on SO and got some reputation there, but only come to meta if I find a bug or really badly want a feature. I use the search and find the exact same feature request I would ask for, but can't vote it up, because I'd need some reputation on meta. Normally, I'm just annoyed and go back to SO and live with it.

In my opinion, it would be helpful to give users from SO, SF or SU there highest reputation on meta, so they could use all the features and one would see, they got a lot points and know the platform well.

(Maybe I get some rep. through this question and can vote on the "someone also commented on a question you commented on"-feature)

Comment: They're either entitled to their rep over there or they're not

Comment: consolatory +1 so that you can cast that vote you mentioned :)

Comment: See here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/why-not-merge-reputation-across-so-sf-and-su

Comment: @Rich Seller: I thought rep was a way to enable certain features for users who know what they are doing (i.e. who are active/successful in one of the "real" sites). I don't see why I should earn the right to edit posts *again*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried associating your accounts under account associations in your profile.

Since your already associated the order of association may not be working. The rep boost only applies if you have more then 200 rep on any other site. However your welcome to try and to remove your association and reapply. I am not sure if this will work and give you the boost if you have since gained 200 rep on the other sites.

Overall your trust on the rest of the sites does not mean we trust you on Meta. And gaining 15 points on Meta is not extremely hard to do either way if you provide a good answer or question.

Comment: It does work. :w00t: I have one hundred and one lovely points.

Comment: Write something so we can downvote you!

Comment: :shakefist: Meanie!

Comment: Protip: copy-paste the second paragraph into vim, press Esc, type `:%s/your/you<Enter>` then `:%s/your/you're<Enter>`. ;)

Answer (score 5):

The 100 rep gained by associating an account to your meta profile is more than enough. We all have to gain reputation on meta, it's not something that's just given out. Look at **Jon Skeet**. He's the top user on SO, yet he's also added nearly 15k worth of reputation here, making him the 3rd user on the site.

A person with a higher rep on meta usually knows when they're dealing with duplicates, how the sites work and what bugs have been solved or not, how things have to be tagged. Again, remember that reputation has to be earned, no matter what the site. It shows you how the community looks at you.

Answer (score 2):

I think the one hundred points for associating accounts is enough. As [Diago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25262/should-we-give-users-their-highest-so-sf-or-su-rep-on-meta/25263#25263) points out above if you did not have the points on SO when you associated your accounts first time round, clear all associations and re-associate.

I think this makes a better balance between a direct link and none, if respected enough else where you get the points to be able to vote up (or vote two people down. Moohahaha) but that is it.