# Different accounts on different sites, why?

Tags: discussion, linked-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why not merge reputation across SO, SF, and SU?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/why-not-merge-reputation-across-so-sf-and-su)

It seems you need a different account on all 4 of these sites, even though the openid can be the same.  You also have independent rating systems.

Why not just have one location of names and reputation, rather than 4 separate ones.  I am a programmer, but dabble in IT stuff at work(so just for work I use stackoveflow and serverfault).  When I am home I am also a hobbyist and use superuser and now I am writing you and needed a 4th account.

I just feel one rating's system with a uniform user-base will add to consistency and ease of use for your users.

Comment: You know, I searched and searched and searched. I could not find anyone else asking this question until I found this, but that was after I had posted pretty much the same question already. (Man, do I feel like a douche).

<a href="http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28414/reputation-migration-propagation-thoughout-so-community-sites">Reputation Migration / Propagation Thoughout SO Community Sites</a>.

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/why-not-merge-reputation-across-so-sf-and-su and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1951/make-superuser-an-aggregate-of-so-and-sf-reputation-closed

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that your expertise at being a developer does not equal your expertise as a sysadmin.

It's pretty simple, really - you're in a new community, so you have a new reputation.

It'd be like asking why do you have to make friends and network when you move from one city to another, even though you were well-known where you came from - it's because it's new.

---

though, fwiw, if you have a high-enough rep on one site, when you associate the other sites you *do* get a 100 rep bump.