# SO rep should count a little on MSO

Tags: feature-request, reputation, linked-accounts

I came here to request a feature on SO, but my feature was already requested.  This means that it's wrong for me to post it as a question.  I'm supposed to upvote the question.  However, I'm not allowed to because I only have 1 rep.

Therefor, there's no way for me to show that I want that feature on SO, where I do have rep (so close to 1000...)  Since MSO is a website for talking about SO, it'd be really cool if my SO rep counted some here.

I was thinking the solution would be that the limits for MSO would be either you have n rep here or you have n*10 rep on SO or one of the other sites.

So if I want to upvote, I need either 15 rep on MSO or 150 rep on my linked account on SO.

Other ideas for making this work would be great too.

Comment: Don't you get 100 rep for just associating with an account that has at least 200 rep?

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying

Comment: -1: there is already mechanism in place that makes your rep from sister sites count.

Answer (score 7):

Click on your name (at the top). Click **Accounts** > Click **Associate Accounts**.

You will get 100 reputation **if** you have 200 reputation on the site you are associating with.

Meta is not the same as SO, so the reputations are not directly linked. However, that 100 reputation is to get you past the newbie abilities.

Comment: I don't have those 100 reputation.  My only thought is that perhaps I associated them before I had 200 rep.  It'd be nice if there was a way I could get those points now (without clearing the association and reassociating.)

Comment: @clahey Clearing and Re-associating is not very hard..

Answer (score 2):

This is not actually a duplicate of

[Why not merge reputation across Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/why-not-merge-reputation-across-so-sf-and-su)

In fact, we are thinking that all new SE sites (the [ones launched democratically by the community](http://blog.stackexchange.com/post/518474918/stack-exchange-2-0)) will have a child meta.* site associated with them on day one. It will behave much like this one does, but on a site-specific basis.

(the current meta, the one you are on now, is more of a meta-meta at that point -- a national government office versus the regional/state government office.)

And, your reputation on the meta site will be more closely related to the parent site.

We're still working out the details on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rep from associating accounts (which helps lower the barrier to entry a bit, in a good way), but beyond that they're pretty orthogonally-related.

So gaining reputation as a good developer (or at least, one with good answers to development questions) means very little when it comes to understanding what is best for the SO *site* itself.  Same would go for anyone who would think that SF or SU account rep should count for anything here.