# Migrate view privileges?

Tags: feature-request, privileges

Once granted on one of the SE sites, the "view vote counts" and "view close votes" privileges should be granted on other stack sites too. These two privileges do not let you mess up anything on the low-rep sites (which you presumably would if you had **all** your edit privileges. Not!) and furthermore, not having them degrades the user experience, I find.

**Update:**

I did not mean to rant about missing edit/vote privileges and have no problems with the ads.
My point is. It is not a privilege to see something that I can access through the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/s/1049/vote-count-per-post):

```
DECLARE @PostId int  = ##PostId##

SELECT vt.Name, COUNT(*) 
FROM Votes v
    INNER JOIN VoteTypes vt ON v.VoteTypeId = vt.Id
WHERE v.PostId = @PostId
GROUP BY vt.Name
```

Comment: Variations on a theme: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29846/can-i-move-reputation-from-stack-overflow-to-server-fault-why-not http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15117/should-so-rep-be-considered-in-su-and-sf http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80440/suggestion-carry-over-some-reputation-between-stackexchange-sites http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15138/why-isnt-reputation-common-between-stack-overflow-sites http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49202/so-rep-should-count-a-little-on-mso

Comment: @random, I agree that those are variations on the theme, especially if you consider *the theme* what I wrote in parenthesis. However viewing something that is also available through the data explorer is not a privilege. It should just be there. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

Erm... **No** Why?

We don't do that for any other privileges. The same could be said for down votes and the whole set of reputation based privileges.

It's just that. A privilege, and it needs to be earned. And to earn it you need to work for it.

And just exactly how does seeing the up and down votes improve the user experience? I hardly ever look at it, and if I do, I have a specific reason too. It has never bothered me whether I can or cannot view it on sites I don't have the privilege.

Comment: If it's a privilege that needs to be earned then how come I can query the data in the data explorer? :-P

Comment: @Klaus... Erm. The Data Explorer is a month behind because it's generated off the data dumps and not the live database? In fact I think the Data Explorer is now only updated by monthly, and the purpose of it is for you to query data yourself? From the Data Explorer FAQ: How frequently is Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?
Data is updated monthly. Also, there is maybe 1% of all the SO users that will ever use the SEDE to bypass a privileges? I can think of better privileges I would like to be able to transfer if it was being considered.

Comment: But how is it harmful that I see it though. I'm not saying that it is a feature that I use *all the time* but my process of thought when I click on the number next to a question and nothing happens is: Did the javascript just break? Let me start firebug up, ah, no hang on, I'm not on SO anymore because this bookmark points to a migrated question...

Comment: @Klaus It is not about being harmful. It's about the **amount of processing required** to retrieve those values. Either way, it's a feature that was requested, and is hardly used. My issue is making an exception for something by "transferring a privilege", which sets a president, and also the team has better things they can spend their time on. You can get the data from the SEDE. So where's the problem?

Comment: @Diago, fair enough. I can easily understand your point about not wanting to transfer privileges. I didn't realize, though, that the amount of high rep users that use more than one SE site is so great that the cpu-cost of displaying this extra piece of information would incur a substantial extra cost for you guys. But I guess I think about a privilege as the ability to do something, more than the ability to view some otherwise public information.

Comment: But, hey, I agree to disagree on this. But to me it is an unnecessary degradation of the user experience. Not as intrusive as a monochrome stylesheet for the iPad, but still an annoyance.