# How about a shared reputation?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why not merge reputation across SO, SF, and SU?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/why-not-merge-reputation-across-so-sf-and-su)

Recently I've had a few questions migrated. One went to webmasters.stackexchange.com, one went to wordpress.stackexchange.com, and one went to superuser.com. I don't disagree with the migration of the questions, but it would be nice to have a **shared reputation** because without such a thing it is hard to participate / follow / discuss across multiple sites.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered before.  But to your specific point:

> it is hard to participate / follow /
>   discuss across multiple sites.

Even with the minimum rep, you still have the ability to follow / participate / discuss.   With the exception of commenting on other's posts.  Which the 100 bonus rep should provide that privilege.

Comment: You can't have 0 rep. 1 is the minimum.

Comment: @N, true, but I was making a point that rep is not needed to participate.

Comment: Type at least the first three characters of my name to trigger notification.