# One login for all the SE sites

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, user-accounts

Everywhere I go, I am asked to create a new account. Why don't all Stack Exchange sites have a single login credential and reputation carrying?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why not all stack sites have a single login detail

They do. It's called OpenID. It's  username / password from a single provider - Google/ Yahoo /Stack Exchange. You can use the same across all Stack Exchange sites.

> reputation carrying.

I don't agree, and this has been [shot down before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/why-not-merge-reputation-across-so-sf-and-su). Repuation is a measure of how much the community trusts you - just because you have semi-decent programming skills doesn't mean you will have the equivalent server admin skills and as such you much prove that you can be trusted. A separate rep system per site ensures that.

Comment: Good answer. To add on to the first part, joining a new site *does* ask you to create a new account on that site, and that is exactly what you're doing. It's just that the new account is automatically associated with your other existing accounts. See also: [“Create New Account” means “Associate Old Account”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58048/create-new-account-means-associate-old-account)

Comment: But why are there even multiple accounts rather than just one?  Especially when you're trying to promote all the other exchanges on the sidebar, it's frustratingly awkward to participate even with a comment on these.