# Sharing the reputation among all the Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why not merge reputation across SO, SF, and SU?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/why-not-merge-reputation-across-so-sf-and-su)

I don't understand why all the sites have their own respective reputation score? Why can't they bring everything under one ID and share the reputation?

Comment: you're right, it shouldn't go here. it should go in meta (you'll find it in the top bar)

Comment: server / network administration, programming and home computer / application might have some relationship but they are still separate areas and skill in one area doesn't guarantee skill in another, hence reputation is not shared. A bricklayer isn't a plumber just because they both work on houses, and not even if you happen to know a plumber that once built their own garden wall.

Comment: Pretty sure [this has been suggested before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/why-not-merge-reputation-across-so-sf-and-su).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because someone that knows a lot about [computer programming](https://stackoverflow.com/) doesn't necessarily know a lot about [cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), and showing a high rep on [the other sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) would be deceptive.

Comment: But sites liker server fault and super user are pretty closely knit right ?

Comment: Software development, systems administration, and application use have little in common other than they all involve computers. Beyond that, they're completely different.

Comment: Application use includes playing games, and games are related to game development, and game dev requires programming, and programmers often have CS degrees, therefore rep on Super User should transfer to cstheory.SE, QED. Taking the transitive closure would end up including almost every site. :]