# Can I combine reputation of area51 and stackoverflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, area-51

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why not merge reputation across SO, SF, and SU?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/why-not-merge-reputation-across-so-sf-and-su)

How do I combine the reputation from two different SE sites?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot combine reputation from different Stack Exchange sites.