# Remove new user restrictions based on merged reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, question-restrictions

### The story

Recently I wanted to ask a programming career related question on SO. However I felt like it wasn't the best SE platform to ask it and I checked what was the "rule" for posting programming career questions. I found on Meta SE that Programmers SE seemed to be the most appropriate place to ask my question. Even though I am quite new here, I felt like a good SE citizen when I headed over to Programmers SE to ask my question. But then I couldn't because it had too many links in it and I felt very frustrated because of these new user restrictions and got very tempted to go back and ask that question on SO...

### In short

I understand that reputation shouldn't be merged across the platform, but maybe the new user restrictions could me removed once and for all of them. In that sense, my question is a bit different from that other one found on Meta SE: [Why not merge reputation across Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/why-not-merge-reputation-across-so-sf-and-su)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's precisely what the "Association Bonus" is for. As soon as you reach 200 reputation points on any Stack Exchange site, it's assumed that you have a grasp on the basic user functions of the software and so you are granted 100 reputation points on all of the Stack Exchange sites where you have a profile.

That "free" 100 points gives you access to (at least) the following [privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges):

- create chat rooms
- edit community wiki
- set bounties
- comment everywhere
- talk in chat
- flag posts
- vote up
- create wiki posts
- remove new user restrictions
- participate in meta

Comment: And that proves that I may not be ready for it yet! Thank you and sorry about (a) the duplicate (b) not finding that by myself. That makes sense and I don't have any issue with it.