# Could we transfer the comment privilege?

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments, privileges

I know [why the 50 reputation requirement exists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). Mainly to prevent spam and unhelpful comments by new users.

My issue is: When I come from other Stack Exchange sites and collected some reputation there, I am apparently not a bot and also know how SE works. But I have to start all over again, which is frustrating.

#### Example

I am currently trying to use Linux, so I created an account on Ask Ubuntu and the Linux Stack Exchange site. An answer that was posted there didn't work, and I wanted to ask for additional help, but I couldn't comment. Opening another question would probably lead to a duplicate. I am also bugged by the suggestion to go find some other questions and earn reputation first, since I need the help now.

So the only option left for me is to go to a forum and ask my question there, which I don't want to do, but I am implicitly urged to do that.

### Suggestion

Unlock comment privilege for all sites either by getting it on one (or a specific amount of sites) or according to your global reputation, which would be the accumulated reputation amongst all SE sites, and require maybe 200 global rep.

What do you think?

Comment: If you're able to get 200 rep on one site, you will get the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303118/323179), and be able to comment on every site. It's not too high of a bar, really.

Comment: I didn't even know that this existed. Weird that while researching it didn't come up. Now I invested time into writing this post probably in vain...

Comment: I just wanted to clarify: My question is neither badly worded, nor unfitting, nor a duplicate. I was simply lacking information. If you think otherwise comment instead of downvoting.

Comment: Xerus, On meta sites, down-voting can also mean folks simply disagree with the suggestion or premise... as it seems to be the case here.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I'm surprised that so many people are disagreeing with something that was part of the system for some time now. And I'm wondering what the downvoters suggest? Do they suggest we should start with 1rep on new site even if we have a few thousand on others?

Comment: @Xerus on meta, people downvote to signal disagreement. On a feature request this is essential, but on discussion questions it can be a little fuzzy. But people don't always look at tags; they see your title, treat it as an FR, and vote. Here's a tip that works well for me: for discussions, ask about the *core problem* rather than leading with a proposed solution. Or if you want to explore a particular change, cast it as "what would happen if...".  In your case, I might've spun it as "how can we let experienced users comment instead of starting over on each site?", the problem you're facing.

Comment: Arguably might be lack of reseach downvotes - but this isn't exactly one of the more intuitive things about SE, especially when once you get the association reputation, its automatic.

Comment: @Xerus Here's a relevant reading: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying. One thing it suggests is to just explain the problem in the question, then propose your solution in an answer, so if the solution is unpopular, your answer, not your question, gets downvoted, and then you can delete it and get your points back. (cc @MonicaCellio)

Comment: This is already a thing that exists and there is a lot of information about it, so I downvoted at least for lack of research. The idea of using global rep is also a terrible idea at such a low level, 200 across SEN is nothing, so there's another downvote for meta disagreement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your suggestion already exists. As soon as you accumulate 200 rep on one site, you automatically get 100 rep on any site you join/ed.

When you have 200 rep, and you join a new site, you will get the following message in your achievements tab:

> You've earned a bonus of 100 reputation because we trust you on other
>   sites in the network