# Is my reputation and reach on my Stack Exchange linked to my Stack Overflow profile?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I just linked my Stack Overflow profile to my meta.stackexchange profile. Is the platform going to link both reputations and reach together?

Comment: I don't know what "reach" means in this context, but reputation is per-site and is not shared or linked.

Comment: The reached number under your profile @ShadowWizardLoveZelda :D

Comment: Reputation is separate for each site…except the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/323179). Reach is also separate, but it's a completely useless and bogus number anyway.

Comment: don't get hung up on that "people reached" number because: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251661/what-happened-to-the-other-people-my-impact-people-reached-just-dropped

Comment: Thanks for the comment everyone. The answers have been helpful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I have different reputation on each Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260437/why-do-i-have-different-reputation-on-each-stack-exchange-site)

Answer (score 3):

I had anticipated to easily find an answer to this (first) question, but even [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) doesn't explain or really clarify that:

- Yes, reputation is gained per site.

  Exceptions are the meta sites of individual sites on the Stack Exchange network, which reflect the reputation from the main sites, to which this main Meta site is the only exception.

Furthermore,

- "Reach", as in "*people reached*" under the header 'Impact' on a user's profile, is based on the amount of views of contributions of the user on an individual site, and *does* have a separate counter for meta sites.

Comment: Well it's answered in separate places, e.g. [Why do I have different reputation on each Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260437/why-do-i-have-different-reputation-on-each-stack-exchange-site), maybe worth adding links in the FAQ to those discussions.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda I thought I had seen a similar question. I think that one makes for a good duplicate.