# Is it possible to get a combined flair like the ones on Area 51?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, area-51, flair

Is it possible to get a combined flair like the ones on Area 51?

See follower list on the right side of an [A51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications) for examples.

---

[image: sample combined flair with rep circled]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should Combined Flair be offered?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116/should-combined-flair-be-offered)

Comment: See George Stocker's answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53744/13295

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been added.  See

> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/

for more details.

Answer (score 13):

**Note: This app, and the associated website have been offline since 2012.**

---

I created [StackFlair](https://stackapps.com/q/1567/2286) for this very purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**StackImage service has been permanently shut down**

---

I have modified [StackImage](https://stackapps.com/questions/847/stackimage-generating-images-of-questions-and-users-now-with-global-flair) to do just that.

Comment: How do you find your guid?

Comment: @Gnome: Good question! I have created a page [here](http://www.stackimage.quickmediasolutions.com/design_global.php) to help you find it!

Comment: Appears there's a bug, "Invalid GUID Specified" when I use either the email address I have on SO or on Meta (it's not the same).

Comment: @Gnome: Hmmm... that's odd. Using the email in your profile, I get the same error. However, this doesn't match any of your SE accounts, because your gravatar would be this: http://gravatar.com/avatar/2a424baa1ed819ee8f9370774b53a52a?s=128

Comment: @Gnome: Your email for Meta has an MD5 hash of `747f80616d1aa2504890e3b59947a9d6`. If you can figure out which email that is, then that's the one to use.

Comment: @Gnome: And if all else fails, your GUID is **`2eca47e1-6ba7-4461-b71d-5286d258414e`** :)

Comment: Ah, it's the Gravatar ID.  Thanks.  I use different addresses for different sites, using *user+site@example.com,* so I can have custom avatars (even though they're currently set to the same).  Is your [page](http://www.stackimage.quickmediasolutions.com/design_global.php) not handling the plus properly (thus giving the "invalid" message)?  (Looks like the above [address](http://gravatar.com/avatar/2a424baa1ed819ee8f9370774b53a52a?s=128) you used is from my non-plus address, which I used in mail to you before?)

Comment: @Gnome: No, you didn't mail me before. (If you did, I didn't get it.) Basically, whatever email you see in your profile is what the app needs. Does the GUID I gave you work?

Comment: @George: You replied to it (was regarding [StackApplet](http://stackapps.com/q/83/289)). :) Several things are just confusing me tonight, I think, and I'll have to check later.

Comment: @Gnome: Oh, okay. Ya, I got that email. I'll look into it.

Comment: Not sure if still relevant but the link is broken...

Comment: @rene not relevant for about three years, answer better be deleted.