# How about a profile.stackexchange.com?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unified Stack Exchange profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68358/unified-stack-exchange-profiles)

Seeing that S[UFO] can link profiles and that the new SE sites will all be under the same system, how about having a single location for user profiles such as http://profile.stackexchange.com? So, my profile would be http://profile.stackexchange.com/pekalicious or http://users.stackexchange.com/...

Answer (score 4):

I like the idea in general, but the "name" idea doesn't quite work - because user names aren't unique.

User IDs are unique *within a particular site* but not across sites. We'd need a sort of "canonical ID" - possibly seeded from Stack Overflow? Then an API to find the various accounts on all sites would be simple...

Comment: Such a cross SE site id exists, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53734/how-can-i-get-all-users-total-reputation-across-all-sites

Comment: @Richard: Excellent. It's not exactly memorable, mind you...

Answer (score 3):

To some extent, until there's some further discussion on this topic, [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) can be used for this purpose, by allowing you to enable the various Flairs as you desire, and you may place any and all information in various different profile boxes.

However, it's certainly an interesting idea, and in light of SE 2.0, may very well merit a new site as you suggest.