# Unified Stack Exchange profiles

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page

Now that Stack Exchange websites are becoming more and more integrated, I was thinking it would be nice to have unified Stack Exchange profiles. These would be similar to an individual site's profile but would show an 'overview' of the profiles from every other Stack Exchange website. Perhaps, though not necessary, even show a 'combined' section which shows the combined reputation, badges, questions, answers, etc.

I feel that this would serve to decentralize individual site-dedication a bit. In other words, certain users wouldn't feel too bad about developing themselves on another site as well knowing that their work is going towards a metric that takes everything into consideration. Not that I personally feel that way, I'm just saying it could possibly be a solution to those who do.

I just think it would be nice to have an overview of someone's activity/contribution to the family of Stack Exchange websites. This way, instead of linking to my Stack Overflow profile and/or Super User, Server Fault, [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/about), etc., I can just link to one unified profile, perhaps [located under the stackexchange.com domain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54362/how-about-a-profile-stackexchange-com).

This would also serve to show people new to Stack Exchange that these really are a family of websites. That way, if they're not necessarily interested in Stack Overflow itself, they may find a link to [Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), which they're interested in.

Just a thought.

Comment: This would go perfectly with the global flair image. Right now I show that and link to my Programmers.SE account since its the most active, but that doesn't show what else I have done. This would be a really nice feature

Comment: @TheLQ: Thanks, any reason why you didn't put this as an answer? Would bump this question back to the front page I think.

Comment: How about simply a profile on StackExchange.com? As it isn't about anything itself, but points to activity around the network

Comment: So if I understand correctly there is no true separation of profiles, e.g., if profile X on x.stackexchange.com and profile Y on y.stackexchange.com belong to the same user account (say, a log in using the same OpenID) then everyone will be able to tell that X and Y are the same person, right? In that case, I would argue for increased separation, in order to allow user the flexibility to use different profiles (e.g., their real name on StackOverflow and an anonymous handle on myhobby.stackexchange.com) such that other users cannot tell that they in fact the same account/person.

Comment: To elaborate, of course you could have completely different accounts. However, can you simultaneously log in with one account on one StackExchange site and a different account on a different site? But even if so, if a person uses OpenID to log in and has an OpenID provider, then they need two different OpenID accounts to have two different StackExchange accounts. Most likely they cannot log in with two different accounts simultaneously with their preferred OpenID provider. IMHO, this souldn't require logging out and back in again, nor running two differnet web browsers.

Comment: Sorry to be so verbose! But something just occurred to me and I'm wondering if someone can confirm it... First, many popular, modern browsers allow different user profiles that you can switch between (even within the same OS user login), right? Second, if that is the case, then do they each store separate and independent cookie files? If both are yes, then that may solve the problem - create two browser profiles and log in to one set of accounts in one profile, and another set of account (potential on the same sites) in the other profile. Can someone confirm my assumptions are true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has already been implemented. First, click the **network profile** button from your profile on any Stack Exchange site.

[Click "network profile" http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/-670112935.png](http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/-670112935.png)

This will take you to [your Stack Exchange network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/35664), which shows all your accounts and other information.

[image: Screenshot of a Stack Exchange network profile]

Comment: Thanks, I know. :) Though do note this question was asked a year ago.

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña Yeah, that's why I was surprised that no one had answered it yet!

Answer (score 0):

As stackexchange.com sites use OpenID to register users, it is obvious, that every account on every StackExchange site with the same OpenID belongs to the same user. So there will be no collisions if we unify accounts. Also, a unified page, showing all reputations, badges etc. across sites is good idea too.