# How can I write a cross-site Data Explorer query that joins databases on linked accounts?

Tags: support, data-explorer, linked-accounts

[The answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83570/allow-cross-site-queries-in-data-explorer/83581#83581) to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83570) implies that you can write cross-site Data Explorer queries, but the sample query doesn't appear to do what I think it should.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM [StackOverflow.Exported]..[Users] u1
    INNER JOIN [ServerFault.Exported]..[Users] u2 ON u1.Id = u2.Id
```

I had assumed that this would find a linked account between Stack Overflow and Server Fault, but as far as I can tell user IDs are not preserved across the Stack Exchange network. Is it possible to write a query that joins linked accounts across Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: You could probably match them by comparing the `EmailHash` column. Most users (~98% or so) use the same email address for each account.

Comment: Yeah, the Data Explorer doesn't have any association information, so `EmailHash` would be the way to go. You could get associated accounts from the API (or the profile page), and then manually enter IDs for given sites into your query, but that's rather tedious.

Comment: Dynamic cross-site queries seem impossible without some kind of hideous and difficult hack... I've been trying to figure out something with `EXEC` and `CREATE FUNCTION`, but this is way beyond my limited MSSQL ability.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/69700/generate-accountid-comparison) to generate the comparison of `AccountIds` and the resulting [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/168043/accountid-comparison), which is of course interesting to run from different base sites :-)

(This answer used to refer to `EmailHashes`.)

Answer (score 3):

I've taken the idea and query from Mark Hurd and removed the need to do a generate and copy-paste. You can run a multi-database query in one go.

Here is how. The [`EXEC()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement does take a T-SQL string and it will execute that SQL statement.

The [`STRING_AGG`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function takes a string expression and a seperator value that is placed between the string expressions.

When you use the `STRING_AGG` function to take its input from rows in a table, it will produce one string as the function aggregates the rows it is fed.

The string expression needs to be of the type NVARCHAR(max) otherwise you're greeted with the error

> STRING_AGG aggregation result exceeded the limit of 8000 bytes. Use LOB types to avoid result truncation.

and a tactical placed `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), {field})` will resolve this problem.

Putting it all together will [give you this version of the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1267498/generate-accountid-comparison)

```
-- var to hold the complete query as text
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

-- use the STRING_AGG function to get the sql
Select @sql = STRING_AGG(
-- this is the string for each database
-- [Name] is here the name of the database
N'Select ''' + Replace([Name],'','') + N''' As [DatabaseName], '
+ N'Count(*) As [Count] '
+ N'From [' + convert(nvarchar(max),[Name]) + N']..Users fu Join Users u ON fu.AccountId=u.AccountId '
-- this is what gets used to concatenate all those strings
,N' UNION ALL ')
From sys.Databases
Where database_id > 5 -- skip the first 5 databases, they have nothing for us
and Name Like '%'

print @sql -- this gets shown on the Messages tab

exec(@sql) -- this executes the SQL statement that is the @sql variable
```

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the unforgettable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).