# Data Explorer queries most likely to find dormant users that if engaged are likely to become active users

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, users

Currently my thought is the profile of such a user would be that they:

- have not visited the site in a month and posted a answer/comment/question
- have an answer/comment/question on the site
- have been on another SE site in the past day/week/etc

Are there any existing queries that attempt to address the topic of finding dormant users that if engaged are likely to become active users? If not, any suggestions/feedback on my thoughts on how best to find them?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to find such users?

Comment: Even if there is such a query, I'd advice against going around and spamming people to use your site. I'd show up in the results for at least one site, and if someone from that site prompted me to go back, I wouldn't be very happy about it...

Comment: Meaningful engagement is what every spammer would call their activities ;) If I used the site once, I know it's there and I really don't see a point in getting any message about it. You can still comment on my questions or answers in any site, if you have something meaningful to say go for it. But specifically targeting dormant users is a bit icky.

Comment: I just happen to use a different username on MSO, all my site accounts are linked. You get one account per site, and although you can link all of them, you can still put different info on each one. As for why I use that name here, that's obvious, I love Yahoo! answers, where all questions get answers and there are no evil mods.

Comment: `If you can't tell the difference, it's not spam, nor do I agree it's icky.` That's cool, just please never message me about becoming an active user on your beta, if I happen to appear in the query results, regardless of the contents of the message.

Comment: You seem to want to engage dormant users on a beta site, in hopes they will become more active. If I am one of the dormant users, I do not want to be contacted for that purpose, regardless of what your message would say. If I have posted an answer or a question to the beta site and you wish to comment on that, feel free to do it, _but_ I expect your comment to be relevant to my post, otherwise I will flag it.

Comment: What? You haven't clarified what "meaningful engagement" or "[Insert meaningful msg]" means to you, and I've already said that I have no problem if your comments are relevant to my posts. Could you edit your question to tell us _exactly_ what you want to do with said query and exactly what you consider meaningful engagement?

Comment: As you already said, we know each other (in SE terms), I know you mean well and you aren't a spammer, why not show everyone else? Intent alone won't cut it, give us some examples of what you actually mean.

Comment: In any case the data Data Explorer is based upon is out of date enough that it probably wouldn't help you much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Just escalating my comments to an answer, which is still effectively the same as Benjol's.</sub>

As mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83581/147650) cross-site queries are possible, but as implied by comments to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109438/how-can-i-write-a-cross-site-data-explorer-query-that-joins-databases-on-linked#comment282793_109438) you can only match users by `EmailHash' which isn't a perfect join on users.

And the data is half a month out of date on average too.

So, no, it is not worth while trying to use Data Explorer for this.

Comment: +1 Mark Hurd: Thanks, thought your comment deserved being an answer, and given the context of the question upon reflection, is the answer, since the timelessness of the data is ultra important. Again, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, no.

At the present time, it is not possible to perform cross-site queries, so that rules out your third bullet.

Comment: You can do cross-site queries, but you (probably) cannot match users.

Comment: @MarkHurd, wow, that was news to me. Can't quite get my head round the queries for the moment.