# Can Data Explorer be used to find total up/down votes cast across all sites?

Tags: discussion, voting, data-explorer

As the question says, I'm wondering if there's any way to find out the total # of up/down votes I've cast (or some other specified userid) across all sites.

Alternatively, if there's a way to show the top voters across all sites, that would work as well.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109438/how-can-i-write-a-cross-site-data-explorer-query-that-joins-databases-on-linked

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can, it's just not very pretty (or reliable, since it relies on the user having a consistent email hash across sites). Thanks to [Mark Hurd](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147650/mark-hurd) for producing [the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/69700/generate-emailhash-comparison) I modified to create the absurd union block for these queries.

For instance, and as no surprise to anyone, [Community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) is the [top voter across the network](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/72411), with [Gilles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/149076/gilles) and [Pekka](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/138112/pekka) placing a dignified second and third respectively. If you're interested in your personal count, it was [18153 votes as of May 8th](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/72412?UserId=130540) (the last time the Data Explorer was updated).

Ideally, using the user's network ID would be more reliable, but that information is currently not available in the Data Explorer tables. It'd also be nice to avoid that horrible union block, but at the moment this hacky solution is probably the best you're going to get.

Comment: Awesome, that query works fine for what I wanted to see.  Thanks!

Comment: I think the API may yield a more accurate (and less ugly!) answer

Comment: @TimYiJiang I imagine so, for the per-user query. I don't think it would be very easy to replicate the network top voters query with the API, though.

Comment: As [EmailHashes are no longer provided](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221027/147650), this is no longer correct and I believe that, at the moment, you cannot connect the same user across sites.

Comment: @MarkHurd You can use `AccountId`, which is more reliable anyway.

Comment: You can adjust your answer; I have updated query 69700 that you link to to use `AccountId`.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't search for a specific user's votes, including your own — that would compromise the anonymity of voting.

Most vote types (including up and down) have the casting user ID field nulled to preserve said anonymity. Since the `Users` table has the convenient `UpVotes` and `DownVotes` fields, [you can list a given site's most active voters](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/72400/most-active-voters-up-down), but due to the way the Data Explorer works, I'm not sure you could do the top voters across all sites.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1296266) that does this in one go by leveraging some dynamic SQL similar to what [Tim Stone offered in his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135322/158100).

The query needs your AccountId. You can find that number in the url of your [Network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/139603/ward).

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)


create table #sites (name sysname
                   , hostname sysname);

create table #result (site sysname
                    , hostname sysname
                    , q integer
                    , a integer
                    , accept integer
                    , up integer
                    , down integer 
                    )

select @sql = N'insert into #sites' + STRING_AGG(concat(N'
select ''', name ,N'''
     , ''', hostname ,N''' 
from ', quotename(name), N'.dbo.users u
where accountid = ##accountid##
'),N' 
union all')
from (select convert(nvarchar(max),name) name
    -- , convert(nvarchar(max),sitename)  sitename
    -- , meta
    -- , domain
     ,  concat( 
        -- based on an idea from Glorfindel 
        -- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321181
        (case sitename
        WHEN 'Audio' THEN 'video'
        WHEN 'Beer' THEN 'alcohol'
        WHEN 'CogSci' THEN 'psychology'
        WHEN 'Garage' THEN 'mechanics'
        WHEN 'Health' THEN 'medicalsciences'
        WHEN 'Moderators' THEN 'communitybuilding'
        WHEN 'Photography' THEN 'photo'
        WHEN 'Programmers' THEN 'softwareengineering'
        WHEN 'Vegetarian' THEN 'vegetarianism'
        WHEN 'Writers' THEN 'writing'
        WHEN 'Br' THEN 'pt'
        WHEN 'Mathoverflow' THEN concat((meta+'.'), sitename)
        ELSE case when sitename = domain then null else sitename end
        end +'.')
        , (case 
           when sitename <> 'mathoverflow' then (meta+'.') 
           else null 
           end) 
        , (case 
           when sitename <> 'mathoverflow' then concat((domain + '.'), 'com') 
           else 'net' 
           end)
        ) hostname
from (
select name
, case parsename(name,1) 
  when 'Meta' then parsename(name,2)
  else parsename(name,1) 
  end [sitename]
, case parsename(name,1) 
  when 'Meta' then 'meta'
  else null
  end [meta]
  , coalesce(parsename(name,3), parsename(name,2)) [domain]
from sys.databases
where database_id > 5
and (name not like '%.Meta' or name = 'StackExchange.Meta')
) dbs
) dbsall

exec (@sql)


select @sql='';

select @sql = N'insert into #result' + STRING_AGG(concat(N'
select ''', convert(nvarchar(max),name) ,N'''
     , ''', convert(nvarchar(max),hostname) ,N''' 
     , count(distinct case p.posttypeid when 1 then p.id else null end) Q
     , count(distinct case p.posttypeid when 2 then p.id else null end) A
     , count(distinct case v.votetypeid when 1 then v.id else null end) accept
     , count(distinct case v.votetypeid when 2 then v.id else null end) up
     , count(distinct case v.votetypeid when 3 then v.id else null end) down
from ', quotename(name), N'.dbo.users u
inner join ', quotename(name), N'.dbo.posts p on
  p.owneruserid = u.id
inner join ', quotename(name), N'.dbo.votes v on 
 v.postid = p.id and votetypeid in ( 1,2,3)  
where accountid = ##accountid##
'),N' 
union all')
from #sites

exec (@sql)


select 0 [line]
     , 'Grand Total' as [site]
     , sum(q)  [# questions]
     , sum(a)  [# answers]
     , sum(accept) [accept votes]
     , sum(up) [up votes]
     , sum(down) [down votes] 
from #result
union 
select row_number() over(order by q + a desc) [line]
    , site
    , q
    ,a
    , accept
    , up
    , down
from #result
where q + a + accept + up + down > 0
order by 1
```

When run today this is what your result will look like:

[image: number of questions, answers, accept, upvote and downvote, showing row Grand total: 69, 557, 122, 4320, 161 and then rows per site]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the unforgettable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Answer (score 1):

While you can't find how many votes have been cast by another user, you can find out how many you have cast. Just navigate to the summary tab on your user page and scroll to the bottom. There should be a Section titled `x Votes Cast`.

> [image: Votes Cast]

You can also click on the *view more* link to see what kinds of votes you have cast and on what question or answer.

**Note: This method shows how many votes you have cast for a specific site.**