# Where did EmailHash go?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, data-explorer, data-dump, api

There are at least four ways to get to StackExchange data: OData (https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom/), Data Explorer (https://data.stackexchange.com/), XML data dumps (https://archive.org/details/stackexchange), and the API (http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/).

The first three used to have EmailHash as a field in the User object. However, EmailHash is missing from all recent data I can find. This is documented here:

- https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new shows the database schema, with User objects having EmailHash field. However, any search on this field fails to find any rows (see e.g. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/153930/find-user-by-email-hash)
- https://ia600603.us.archive.org/34/items/stackexchange/readme.txt shows that the Users.xml file should have EmailHash. However, all the files in the data dump are missing this field.
- https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom/Users has a field for EmailHash, but it is always NULL.

Could someone who knows explain why EmailHash is not currently being provided? Is this an oversight, or a policy change?

Comment: Probably related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209605/230957

Comment: See also Nick's answer in [Registering on a new site uses Identicon instead of Gravatar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193894/registering-on-a-new-site-uses-identicon-instead-of-gravatar/193901#193901). And for those still using Gravatar's identicon: [you can get a safer one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204523/unexpectedly-changing-identicon/204540#204540).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This was a deliberate change that went in a few weeks ago.

Since it is possible to [get the email address from the hash](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/07/got-an-account-on-a-site-like-github-hackers-may-know-your-e-mail-address/), we no longer release email hashes to better protect people's privacy.

Comment: Thank you. So is there currently another way to find out a user's profile given some information about them, such as their email address? Or are there plans to have such support in the future?

Comment: @Greg I'm not sure if we ever intended users to be discoverable that way. You could identify a user by their display name (which, to be fair, isn't unique), but we have no way (or, far as I know, intent) to allow finding a user profile by knowing any information that isn't otherwise publicly available.