# With SEDE, is there a way to run a query across all sites in the network?

Tags: support, data-explorer

<sup>My apologies if this question is off-topic here, but it is a discussion about how to use a network-wide tool specific to SE.</sup>

The question in its entirety is in the title, really.  How can I use the StackExchange Data Explorer to run a query across all sites in the network?  I cannot seem to find a way to search more than one (set with the drop-down next to `Compose Query`) – is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes! You just can't use it, because it's not enabled on the public-facing instance. This is indeed [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

*Technically* speaking, you can [hack your way around this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109438/how-can-i-write-a-cross-site-data-explorer-query-that-joins-databases-on-linked)*, but I don't recommend it. It's pretty rare that there's a good non-community-management reason to run a query against every single site at once, so being able to switch sites relatively conveniently should be sufficient for most cases. I'm opening to hearing counterexamples, although I don't control what features are enabled on the hosted SEDE.

<sub>*though not exactly as shown there, because `EmailHash` no longer exists, and that was for *joining* cross-site, which is more than what you were asking for anyway</sub>

Comment: For [vermiculus/sx.el#137](https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el/issues/137), I would like to get a rough estimate on how many tags exist throughout the network to estimate how many API calls it would take to retrieve them all.  Since there are just too many to grab for each user (that would be irresponsible), we need a workaround if we want sane tag completion.  The idea is to create a bot that goes through and grabs tags by the batch and dumps them to a file that can just be downloaded and read by the client, but this still relies on thousands of API calls.

Comment: What may have been a better solution if this were not [tag:status-bydesign] would be to run the query once a day or so and scrape the output.  If SEDE runs off of the quarterly dump, though – as I seem to remember it does (?) – I don't know how much that's going to do.

Comment: SEDE is updated via a separate process that runs weekly, though that still might be a too-large window for your purposes. For your estimation purposes, you could write a quick script to sum up tag counts on the SEDE homepage. It does seem like the API should have exposed a tag searching endpoint though, hrm...

Comment: Oh goodness, that was our fallback, though: making a request to the API to search for tags based on current input.  I guess that's out :(

Comment: Ah, I misspoke on that one, the [`/tags` endpoint](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags) does allow searching via the `inname` parameter, so that seems like your most viable option.

Comment: These are in the space of "just curious" rather than "urgent" or "would majorly improve my ability to contribute to SE", but two queries I'd like to be able to run are: (a) on which sites does $user have $badge, and (b) what are the top N sites for $site's top M users (i.e. where else do these users participate significantly).