# Determine overall Stack Exchange reputation rank

Tags: support, reputation, data-explorer, site-crossover

I have earned roughly 27k reputation points in total between all the Stack Exchange sites. I notice that when I follow or commit to an Area 51 proposal, I'm usually one of the highest on it when sorted by user reputation.

How might one go about finding their rank of Stack Exchange reputation? We can do it individually per site, but that's not what I'm looking for exactly.

I have considered something like... pulling a data.stackexchange query of all users with 10k+ rep on each site (just assuming there's not people with 8k rep on four different sites to sneak under the radar) and compiling a list that way, but that is a lot of work and isn't guaranteed to be accurate. And from what I can tell, the data query tool is not capable of hitting multiple databases.

What are my options to solve this incredibly not important problem?

Comment: It seems like it should appear in the [leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/)

Comment: You can do cross-site queries, but being able to join a user cross-site is difficult due to lack of account association information.

Comment: @michael That was my first thought too.

Comment: @Tim Stone - that's a good point. And you can't rely on names either, since they change across sites and who knows how many people call themselves "Jon Skeet" (legitimately or not). (Actually I bet you could know if you did the query but... anywho)

Comment: I've been considering a way to make that more practical, but that's a bit of a back-burner thing at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the [SEDE multi-database query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1267499) that creates the Network-wide league for the same networkaccounts.

What is being build is a massive union of all users from all databases and their reputation. Across all database the AccountId is the same for a specific user (as opposed to the Id, which is different per database). Once we have the union all we need is to sum the reputation grouped over the accountid. Order by that Sum in descending order and you have your league.
We need some boilerplate to build this query in a string first before we can actually execute which makes it a tad harder to follow in the actual query.

This is the query:

```
-- var to hold the complete query as text
declare @sql nvarchar(max)


-- use the STRING_AGG function to get all SQL
-- projection over the complete result
Select @sql = N'
SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sum(reputation) desc) [rank]
     , concat(
       ''https://stackexchange.com/users/''
       , accountid
       , ''|''
       ,  min(displayname)
       ) as [Network Link]
     , sum(reputation) [Network reputation]
FROM  ('
+ STRING_AGG(
-- this is the string for each database
-- [Name] is here the name of the database
N'Select displayname
       , reputation
       , accountid
From ' + convert(nvarchar(max),quotename([Name])) + N'..Users'
-- this is what gets used to concatenate all those strings
,N' 
UNION ALL 
')
-- the data and grouping over the inner query
+ ') data
group by accountid
order by sum(reputation) desc
'
From sys.Databases
Where database_id > 5 -- skip the first 5 databases, they have nothing for us
-- let's not include meta sites, except MSE
and (Name not Like '%.Meta' or Name = 'StackExchange.Meta')

print @sql -- this gets shown on the Messages tab

exec(@sql) -- this executes the SQL statement that is the @sql variable
```

When run today this is the result:

[image: Showing a league with 1. Jon Skeet, 2. Gilles, 3. egreg, 4.VonC etc]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the unforgettable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Comment: It's been a while but you once helped me write such a query: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313522/295232

Comment: Hmm. I came higher than expected (#732) :)

Comment: Excellent - and just in time for someone to... close it for being a duplicate... even though it isn't...

Comment: @Glorfindel yeah, I was on a quest to see if I could revisit some techniques to make them easier to follow, eliminating stuff. But yeah, a dupe.

Comment: I see now that it is indeed a dupe - the question title is misleading, because it asks for the sum, but when I look more at the answer it is indeed a dupe... Okie dokie.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment I think your best option is to narrow your scope, and query each site individually.  It's a pain, but there's no other easy way since not everyone is on Area51 (if they were, you could just scrape that).

Similar to http://stackathlon.appspot.com/ you should consider only those users with X reputation or higher and set up your queries to ignore user accounts on sites where the users have less than X reputation.

For instance, you might set X to 10k, as you will find hundreds of people with over 10k just on stack overflow alone.  You will miss people who have 9k on many sites, but they will still rank very low on the scale, and it wasn't too long ago that jeff mentioned in a comment that there are actually relatively few people who get over 1k on more than a few sites (as an example, see the above linked stackathlon site).

Now you have to connect accounts. Take one person, scrape their accounts page for the URLs to their other site's accounts, and remove their other accounts from your list (so you don't do it multiple times for the same person).  At the same time collect their rep from sites they also participate in, but weren't over X.  This way you will have complete rep points for everyone who was on the list, and their account associations.

You should be able to rank everyone at this point.

Again, you'll have missed someone if they have 5k points on 50+ sites, but that is rare enough that it's not likely to change even if you set X to 1k and collected most of the active stack exchange users.  But you could scrape all the account pages at the 1k and up level if you wanted.  It would just take a long time since the system isn't scraper friendly.  Unfortunately this information does not appear to be accessible via the data exchange.