# List of Stack Exchange Users By Reputation

Tags: support, reputation

Is there some way to get a visual or list of every Stack Exchange user in each sub site by reputation and badges or is this information private?

Comment: The sidebar of [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/week/meta) probably helps. Also, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users) and https://data.stackexchange.com may be helpful.

Comment: How do I see my total score?

Comment: Add all your reps [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/13547305/cody-rutscher?tab=accounts)

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53734/158100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack Exchange main site/portal hosts the [reputation leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues), where you can see a listing of the top ranking users with 200+ rep per site, per time period (or overall).