# Flair for my total SE rep as shown on Area51

Tags: feature-request, area-51, stack-exchange, flair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a combined flair like the one on area51.stackexchange.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52089/how-to-get-a-combined-flair-like-the-one-on-area51-stackexchange-com)

I would like a way to show flair for my total Rep and badges as is done on area51.

[image: Image with rep circled]

Comment: Related: [How can I get all users' total reputation across all sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53734/how-can-i-get-all-users-total-reputation-across-all-sites)

Comment: @Jon Seigel, I'd be fine with that one, but it's not a `feature-request`.  And it doesn't have a picture.

Comment: @C. Ross - edit them in

Comment: @squillman Done.