# Anyone have code for combined flair with mouseover tooltip info?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm thinking the functionality in Area51, where hovering over the icon of a site shows the reputation on *that* site in the tooltip.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get a combined flair like the ones on Area 51?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52089/is-it-possible-to-get-a-combined-flair-like-the-ones-on-area-51)

Comment: Click on the "got flair?" link under the picture in your user profile.

Comment: Not a duplicate.  I know where the combined flair is, what I miss is the hovering bit (is it really that unclear?  Okay, rephrasing time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only official flair format is the image format offered via your profile page.  You could take a look at http://stackapps.com and search for flair there.

Of the flair options on StackApps, I'd recommend http://stackflair.com personally though. (:  You can get an html version which provides tooltips for the different elements.

Comment: "Of the flair options on StackApps, I'd recommend http://stackflair.com". Subtle :)

Answer (score 1):

Since HTML does not allow you to assign alt or title texts to specific parts of an image, and since non-image based flair is not available, this is not possible through Stack Exchange, nor is it likely to be offered, based on the following quote:

> **What about the old, non image based
>   flair?**
>
> The earlier methods of sharing flair
>   are deprecated and will go away
>   eventually. Please use the simpler
>   image flair from this point onward!

From https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair

Options that use the API are [available](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/flair), with [StackFlair](http://www.stackflair.com/)'s HTML based version providing the mouseover text you want.