# How do I show my combined flair?

Tags: support, combined-flair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to get a combined flair like the ones on Area 51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52089/is-it-possible-to-get-a-combined-flair-like-the-ones-on-area-51)

I am a member of Stack Overflow and Area 51, among others. I have 800+ reputation points on Stack Overflow and 260+ on Area 51. I would like to have my multiple memberships reflected on the flair as it appears on Stack Overflow and Area 51. I noticed, for example, that many other members of Are a51 have multiple Stack Exchange accounts listed on their flairs. I believe I've linked my accounts, but I am unable to see the combined info in the flair.

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to do to have the combined info show up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your [flair page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/389051/gene-golovchinsky/flair) and the code is in the **second** text box. You can find that link by visiting your profile and looking in the links at the top (edit prefs **flair** my logins apps).

[image: Combined flair]

```
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/165524">
<img src="https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/165524.png" width="208" height="58" alt="profile for Gene Golovchinsky on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites" title="profile for Gene Golovchinsky on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites">
</a>
```

The per-site flair and the combined (network) flair are separate images.

Comment: Thanks! I had seen that before; I just don't understand what I need to do to get that to appear on the Stack Exchange sites (such as on this page).

Comment: Do you mean up where it says "asked 1 hour ago"? You cannot change what is displayed there. The flair image is just something you can use on external sites. Specific sites will **never** show your full network details instead of that specific site's details in those areas, **only** Area 51 does that because it's actually relevant there.

Comment: OK, I get that. What's the right way to either get the combined flair to show up on Area51 (which it doesn't at the moment), or where is the right place to ask that question?

Comment: @Gene: Did you just recently link your accounts together? I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be showing your Stack overflow in your Area51 flair.

Comment: It's been a couple of days or so... I am glad that I wasn't missing anything that I had to do.

Comment: @Gene: I would reword your question to ask why your Stack overflow account isn't showing up specifically in your Area51 flair when it meets the minimum 200 reputation requirement. Include that you recently linked the accounts, and change it to a [bug] report. A developer could look into that issue better.