# Combined Flair for all Stack Exchange network

Tags: feature-request, flair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a combined flair like the one on area51.stackexchange.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52089/how-to-get-a-combined-flair-like-the-one-on-area51-stackexchange-com)

Could you add an awesome Flair that combines all the reputations\badges gained on all the Stack Exchange network?

Something like that is already present on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352?phase=definition).
Here an example:

[image]

Related question:
[Should Combined Flair be offered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116/should-combined-flair-be-offered)

Comment: What's the difference between that question and this one?

Comment: The real difference is the existence of Are51 and SE - the other question discusses the trilogy and the "future SU".

Comment: No one is saying you didn't search, but it could be [easier to find duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27566/would-it-be-feasible-to-tie-the-tags-of-a-new-question-to-the-related-questions-l) (notice the duplicate is currently fifth in the "related" list here).